# How to make a say embed command in Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm new to coding and am making a Discord bot for a friend. They are requesting a say command that could act as a confession command where it would look like this. An embed with a set Title, set color, and completely anonymous but with an editable description that would fill in with what they want to confess. As i'm new to coding I don't know how to do this. If anyone can help that would be really appreciated! Thank you!

(Edit) I realise that i wasn't through enough about what the code was so im making an edit with my main.js code.

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = 'wtf ';

const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
 
 
bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Tomoko is online!');
});
 
bot.on('message', async msg =>{
    if(!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(msg, args, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'creator'){
        client.commands.get('creator').execute(msg, args, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'help'){
        client.commands.get('help').execute(msg, args, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'kick'){
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(msg, args, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'ban'){
        client.commands.get('ban').execute(msg, args, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'mute'){
        client.commands.get('mute').execute(msg, args, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'unmute'){
        client.commands.get('unmute').execute(msg, args, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'warn'){
        client.commands.get('warn').execute(msg, args)
    } else if (command === 'deletewarns'){
        client.commands.get('deletewarns').execute(msg, args);
    } else if (command === 'warnings'){
        client.commands.get('warnings').execute(msg, args);
    }     if (args[0].toLowerCase() === 'confess') {
        const description = args.splice(1).join(" ");
        const embed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle('✦┊‧๑ ꒰<a:ccc:862524564457390150><a:ooo:862524674185101322><a:nnn:862524667368833024><a:fff:862524592202973244><a:eee:862524583802568714><a:sss:862524709782683648><a:sss:862524709782683648>꒱ ‧๑┊✧').setColor('ffaaaa').setDescription(description);
        await msg.delete().catch(e => console.log(e));
        msg.channel.send(embed);
    } else if (command === "unban"){
client.commands.get('unban').execute(msg, args, Discord);
        
      ;}
});


client.login('DAMN YOU WISH I WOULD SHOW YOU');
```

So if possible can anyone give me the advanced command handler say embed command. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you handle your commands. But in general: generate a new embed, and set the description to the contents of your message.

Check [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview) on how to create an embed.

Answer (score 1):

A simple bot to do your job

```js
// importing dependencies
const { MessageEmbed, Client } = require('discord.js');
const prefix = '!';
const bot = new Client(); // init discord client

bot.on('ready', () => console.log('yee im on'));

// listening for messages
bot.on('message', async msg => {
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) return // dont run if the prefix is not used
    const args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" "); // creating array of the message contents
    if (args[0].toLowerCase() === 'say') { // a simple command handler
        const description = args.splice(1).join(" ");
        const embed = new MessageEmbed().setDescription(description); // setTitle and stuff according to your preference
        await msg.delete().catch(e => console.log(e)); // deleting the user message since it should be anonymous
        msg.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
bot.login('yourtokenhere');
```

Make sure to replace token and prefix with your token and prefix

How to run the command :

```
!say ooh this is a confession
```